# Associate a type level optional natural number (Maybe Nat) with a value

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

The function [`natVal :: forall n proxy. KnownNat n => proxy n -> Integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) associates a type level natural with an `Integer` value. Using `DataKinds`, `TypeApplications` language extensions one can do

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Derp where

import           Data.Proxy                     ( Proxy(..) )
import           GHC.TypeLits                   ( natVal )

foo :: Integer
foo = natVal (Proxy @1337)
```

How would one associate a `'Maybe Nat` to a value? e.g. a `Maybe Integer`

```
foo2 :: Maybe Integer
foo2 = maybeNatVal (Proxy @(Just 1337))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the singletons package does. The relevant function is named `demote`. `demote`, specialized with a type-level value (with a visible type application), is equal to the corresponding term-level value.

One difference to mention is that `Nat` demotes to `Natural`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, DataKinds #-}
import Data.Singletons
import Numeric.Natural (Natural)  -- base

myexample :: Maybe Natural
myexample = demote @('Just 1337)
```

Answer (score 4):

The same thing we always use to convert types to values: typeclasses.

```
class MaybeNatVal (v :: Maybe Nat) where
  maybeNatVal :: Proxy v -> Maybe Integer
instance MaybeNatVal Nothing where
  maybeNatVal _ = Nothing
instance KnownNat n => MaybeNatVal (Just n) where
  maybeNatVal x = Just $ natVal $ unJust x
    where unJust :: Proxy (Just n) -> Proxy (n :: Nat)
          unJust _ = Proxy
```

The library suggested in the other answer does the same thing, except the typeclass is polymorphic and the instances are generated by Template Haskell.